# How to substitute a list of words based on a list of tuples by preserving the same original order?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

Given the following list of tokens:

```
a = ['heyyo', 'how', 'ale', 'yiou']
```

And a list of tuples:

```
b = [('yiou', 'you'), ('heyyo', 'hello')]
```

How can I replace the elements of the list `a` considering the elements of the list `b`? For example, the expected output would be:

```
['hello', 'how', 'ale', 'you']
```

This is due to list `b` has as a replacement:`yiou` for `you` and `heyyo` for `hello`. How to make the above replacement securing the same original order of list `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dict on `b` and then search each item of `a` in `dct_b` with [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). If exist return `value` base `key` and if doesn't exist return the item.

```
dct_b = dict(b)
res = [dct_b.get(item, item) for item in a]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'how', 'ale', 'you']
```

Comment: `dict(b)` would be enough for mapping

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any way of doing this with queues? Something like dequeueing the list by fixing a pivot?

Comment: @JDo why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am just curious to learn how this concept would apply to this case

Answer (score 3):

Too late, but at least short :-)

```
res = [*map(dict(b).get, a, a)]
```